# Angular 6, color from css file in ngStyle directive

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-style

I would like to use my color which is defined in CSS file for my **ngStyle** directive (which is in HTML).

This is what i've got in my HTML:

```
 [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: isDarkStyle() ? '#29434e' : isNormalStyle() ? '#cfd8dc' : isLightStyle() ? 'white': ''}"
```

This my CSS file with colors:

```
//colors for background

$light-background: white;
$normal-background: #cfd8dc;
$dark-background: #29434e;
```

**But i want this:**

```
[ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: isDarkStyle() ? '$dark-background' : isNormalStyle() ? '$normal-background' : isLightStyle() ? '$light-background': ''}"
```

How can I achieve this result? Thanks for help :)

Comment: Why you don't use ngClass

Comment: Because my CSS classes are very big and i want to only change one thing (background-color). If I use ngClass i have to build 3 big CSS classes with only one change (which is background color)

Comment: You can still use ngClass with multiple classes. Try to apply your main class and a color class just after. Latter class will have higher priority, therefore will override main class bg color. 

[ngClass]="{'mainClass':true,'darkstyleClass':isDarkStyle())"

Comment: Sass variables cannot be resolved at runtime, they've been precompiled in your CSS output. You will need to use native CSS variables or CSS classes for this to work.

Comment: @GorkaHernandez that correct that

Comment: @KacperKapela in this case you will define classes or varibles with color value , the classes is much better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[ngClass]`

See stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-refjye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```
.light{
background: white;
}
.normal{
background: #cfd8dc;
}
.dark{
background: #29434e;
}
```

in Html

```
<p [ngClass]="isDarkStyle() ? 'dark' : isLightStyle() ? 'light': isNormalStyle()?'normal':''">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

Comment: hey.. tell me for more help

Comment: but my CSS classes are way bigger. They don't have only one property. If i use ngClass i have to build 3 very big classes with only one change (which is background color)

Comment: no! it add another class to the list(the selector will have tow class one yours and one the color)

Comment: i tried to run that code but it says ' { statement expected'

Comment: see deit and see blitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-refjye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: it doesn't work good. It overwrites my main big CSS class to one from these three little classes

Comment: (https://pastebin.com/cfGhLkwy) And i want to change background-color of my "aside" class.

Comment: but when I use ngClass it overwrites my 'aside' class to one of these three little classes with one property.

Comment: see here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-refjye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: yes! that works as i expected! thank you so much man :) this '!important' really did difference :D

Answer (score 1):

[try solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frg1su)

As I understood your queston:

HTML:

```
<h1 [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: isDarkStyle() ? 'red' : isNormalStyle() ? 'green' : isLightStyle() ? 'white': ''}">Text</h1>
```

TS:

```
isDarkStyle() {
    return false
  }

  isNormalStyle() {
    return true
  }

  isLightStyle() {
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: my code is working fine but i want this colors (red, green, white) to have in my CSS file

Answer (score 0):

You can defined `ngClass` or `ngStyle`

**ngClass** required to define class in your style file

```
<h1>ngClass</h1>
<p [attr.class]="state">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<button (click)="state = 'light'">light</button>
<button (click)="state = 'dark'">dark</button>
<button (click)="state = 'normal'">normal</button>
```

**ngStyle** you can change spisifc css properties like `background-color`

```
<h1>ngStyle</h1>
<p [ngStyle]="{'background-color':color}">
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<button (click)="color = '#fff'">light</button>
<button (click)="color = '#cfd8dc'">dark</button>
<button (click)="color = '#29434e'">normal</button>
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-color-switch)